# MenuItem doesn't appear in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm facing a problem. I can't make a toolbar to show me a menu. I know that this question was asked here previously here, and I went through all possible solutions, but none of them gave me desired result. So I'm using 1 activity and few fragments and I want to show different menu items in a toolbar according to fragment. Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView drawerView;
    NavController navController;
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    ConstraintLayout container;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerView = findViewById(R.id.drawer_view);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        container = findViewById(R.id.container);

        drawerView.bringToFront();
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        //NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_main, R.id.navigation_favourite,
                R.id.navigation_add_announce,R.id.navigation_notifications,
                R.id.navigation_profile).setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout).build();

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(drawerView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
        drawerView.setCheckedItem(R.id.drawer_main);
        drawerView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        animateDrawer();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_fragment_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And i want to show LogIn text in ProfileFragment toolbar
ProfileFragment.java code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ProfileViewModel mViewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);



        return root;
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_fragment_menu, menu);
    }


}
```

profile_fragment_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
        android:title="@string/enter_acc"<!-- LogIn -->
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

mobile_navigation.xml holds navigation graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
        android:name=".ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_bar_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favourite"
        android:name=".ui.favourite.FavouriteFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_bar_favourite"
        tools:layout="@layout/favourite_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_add_announce"
        android:name=".ui.add.AddFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_bar_add_announce"
        tools:layout="@layout/add_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name=".ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_bar_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/notifications_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:name=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_bar_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_profile_to_registerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
        android:name=".ui.profile.register.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="register_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/register_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

I tried `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.profile_fragment_menu)` in MainActivity within onCreate method
and menu item appeared and was clickable but it was showing on all fragments + onOptionsItemSelected didn't process click on item. My last try you can see in my code. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `Toolbar` as `ActionBar` and use the `ActionBar` API (as `onCreateOptionsMenu`) you have to add `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Otherwise if you don't call `setSupportActionBar` you can use the Toolbar APIs directly and use the method [`inflateMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#inflateMenu(int)) in each fragment. Something like:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.xxxxx)
```

and then use the `setOnMenuItemClickListener` method to set a clickListener.